# HTML5 video tag not working in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, mp4

```
<video preload="true" controls="true" style="width:100%;" id="video-banner" poster="poster-img.png">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I have the above code for showing a video in my browser. This works fine for all browsers, the issue is when I try to play it in iPhone chrome, I can see the video with the poster image and a play button above it. But clicking the play button doesn't work. Basically, the video is not playing only. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the full HTML5 for the page - it helps when trying to understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to play video inline, not full screen. Chrome IOS only supports full screen video playback so you must to add this:

**HTML**

```
<video preload="true" controls="true" style="width:100%;" id="video-banner" poster="poster-img.png" webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**OBJ-C**

```
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

Comment: could you change "webkit-playsinline" with "playsinline"